# Ordering of non-atomic operations through the use of atomic operations as the basis for the higher-level synchronization facilities

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic, memory-barriers

I first cites some description from "C++ concurrency in action" by Anthony Williams :

```
class spinlock_mutex

{

 std::atomic_flag flag;

public:

 spinlock_mutex():

     flag(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT)
 {}

 void lock()

 {

     while(flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
 }

 void unlock()

 {

     flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
 }

};
```

> The lock() operation is a loop on flag.test_and_set() using
>   std::memory_ order_acquire ordering, and the unlock() is a call to
>   flag.clear() with std:: memory_order_release ordering. When the first
>   thread calls lock(), the flag is initially clear, so the first call to
>   test_and_set() will set the flag and return false, indicating that
>   this thread now has the lock, and terminating the loop. The thread is
>   then free to modify any data protected by the mutex. Any other thread
>   that calls lock() at this time will find the flag already set and will
>   be blocked in the test_and_set() loop.
>
> When the thread with the lock has finished modifying the protected
>   data, it calls unlock(), which calls flag.clear() with
>   std::memory_order_release semantics. This then synchronizes-with (see
>   section 5.3.1) a subsequent call to flag.test_and_set() from an
>   invocation of lock() on another thread, because this call has
>   std::memory_order_acquire semantics. Because the modification of the
>   protected data is necessarily sequenced before the unlock() call, this
>   modification happensbefore the unlock() and thus happens-before the
>   subsequent lock() call from the second thread (because of the
>   synchronizes-with relationship between the unlock() and the lock())
>   and happens-before any accesses to that data from this second thread
>   once it has acquired the lock.

Q: If there are only two threads, and thread A has the object `m1` invokes `lock()` for the first time, and thread B has the object `m1` invokes `lock()` for the first time before `m1` invoking `unlock()` in the thread A, why `flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)` get true rather than false (the initial value) when `m1` invokes `lock` function in the thread B?

I know the release sequence, but constituting a release sequence needs an atomic object invoking an atomic operation with `std::memory_order_release` and there is no operation invoked with `std::memory_order_release`.

Comment: The writing style suggests that the code and first two paragraphs are quotes from Antony Williams' book?

Comment: @MSalters Yes, the code and the first two paragraphs are all quotes from Antony William's book.

Comment: @Anthony Williams Could you help me solve the problem above?

Comment: I don't think you can ping book authors like that ;) But Mr. Williams has a consultancy firm, https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/

Comment: I know what you say, but I decide to make a try.

Comment: @Vicente Botet Escriba Could you help me solve the problem above?

Answer (score 1):

The `acquire` and `release` semantics relate to the other (protected) resource, not shown here. In particular, don't move access after the lock or before the unlock. The atomic operations themselves are fully ordered.

Because the operations are fully ordered, your hypothetical order `A:lock, B:lock, A:unlock` is seen in the same order by both threads. Hence, when thread B calls `lock`, it sees only the `lock` from A and not the `unlock`.

Comment: The atomic operations themselves are fully ordered if they invoke operations through std::memory_order_seq_cst. If not, they are not always fully ordered.

Answer (score 1):

The thread doing things before each other doesn't really make sense other than it has the behaviour you wish to know. The memory_order doesn't come into this. It specifies how regular, non-atomic memory accesses are to be ordered around the atomic operation.

The reasons for having it are that if you do:

```
lock();
foo();
unlock();
```

In two threads, foo in one thread cannot read or right before the lock or after the unlock, of the thread in question. This combined with the atomicity of the lock and unlock themselves gives the behaviour we expect. (i.e. no concurrent access from foo).

Answer (score 0):

There is only one `std::atomic_flag`. At any one time, it is either set (`true`) or clear (`false`).

[`std::atomic_flag::test_and_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/test_and_set) is defined as

> Atomically changes the state of a `std::atomic_flag` to set (`true`) and returns the value it held before.

When A has called `lock`, it has changed the flag to set, so the state returned when B tries to lock is set. This is evaluated as the condition of the `while`, so the loop continues. Thread B will continue "spinning" in this loop until the lock is released

Finally when A calls unlock, the flag is changed to clear. Then B can test again, and the `false` ends the loop.

Comment: This answer is very misleading. In multi-threaded code, the concept of "at any one time" simply does not exist. Hence, the statement "At any one time, it is either set or clear" is wrong, and indeed two threads can simultaneously observe different values. (in particular with `memory_order_relaxed`)

Comment: @MSalters The whole point of atomic primitives are to *reintroduce* the concept of "at any one time" to multi-threaded code. The memory order tags distinguish what *other state changes* are synchronised with a particular operation.

Comment: @Caleth I think the concept of "at any one time" should only apply to operations invoked with std::memory_order_seq_cst. Please check C++ Concurrent in Action for the answers.

Comment: @albizzia for a given atomic primitive, there exists a total order of operations that are applied to it. Memory order does not affect that.

Comment: @Caleth: The C++ order of operations depends on `happens-before` and `happens-after`. Since two atomic operations do not necessarily have a `happen-before` relation, there is is no ordering between them. Memory order critically affects this by potentially creating a happens-before order.

Comment: Memory order does not affect the `happens-before` or `happens-after` relation of multiple modifications of **one** atomic object. ["std::memory_order specifies how regular, non-atomic memory accesses are to be ordered around an atomic operation."](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)